# jQuery script not working in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a few different jQuery scripts that I am using with wordpress and all others work fine except for this one:
*Updated to add a fiddle:*

[jsfiddle.net/zq43e9ed](https://jsfiddle.net/zq43e9ed/) 
Only options A and options B can be selected together, if option AA or BB are chosen then A's and B's get de-selected. This works correctly on this fiddle but not when I implement it on wordpress

Below is the code I have used in ajs file for wordpress:

```
jQuery("#silhouette-form").on("click", ".selection", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var all = $("#silhouette-form").find(".selection").not($this);
    var val = $this.val();

    if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
        all.filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() != val;
        }).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

And I have included in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'customize-two-select',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customize-two-select.js',
    array('jquery')
);
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with the jQuery script in question?

Comment: Are there any error in the Chrome developer tool console? Are the file load correctly in the browser? Also, in wordpress the jQuery is set to the noConflict mode, so the $ shortcut for jQuery is not available. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: I have added a fiddle to what im using the script for: https://jsfiddle.net/zq43e9ed/
Only options A and options B can be selected together, if option AA or BB are chosen then A's and B's get de-selected.
This works correctly on this fiddle but not when I implement it on wordpress

Answer (score 1):

If your jquery conflicting with other jquery you can use this technique.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);</script>

<script>
jQuery_1_10_2("#silhouette-form").on("click", ".selection", function () {
var $this = $(this);
var all = $("#silhouette-form").find(".selection").not($this);
var val = $this.val();

if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
    all.filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() != val;
    }).prop("checked", false);
} 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `$` shortcut this way, if you're using the default jQuery that is included with WordPress (which is included in noConflict mode). You either need to use `jQuery` everywhere, or assign the `$` shortcut to it using a wrapper:

```
(function($){
    $("#silhouette-form").on("click", ".selection", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var all = $("#silhouette-form").find(".selection").not($this);
        var val = $this.val();

        if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
            all.filter(function () {
                return $(this).val() != val;
            }).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You can read more about using jQuery in WordPress [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).